# Función VBA no inserta todas las filas

Tags: excel, vba, macros

Estoy haciendo un código en VB para extraer los datos de una tabla en una DB, e insertarlos a una tabla en una hoja de mi libro de Excel, el código actualmente obtiene los datos de la BD completos, pero al insertarlos en la tabla de Excel solo inserta la primera fila del resultado, este código es  lo que tengo:

```
Sub MatPpa()
    Dim cn As Object
    Dim mes As Integer
    Dim anio As Integer
    Dim material_ppa As String
    Dim strConnection As String

    mes = Range("C2").Value ' Obtener el mes
    anio = Range("C3").Value  'Obtener el año
    
    'Construir la cadena de conexión a la base de datos
    strConnection = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=10.210.142.98;Database=YMM_ScrapSystem;Uid=admin;Pwd=abc123/*-;"

    'Conectar a la base de datos
    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    cn.Open strConnection
    
    'Construir la consulta SQL para extraer datos de la tabla 'tabla_scrap'
    material_ppa = "SELECT fecha, kg , tipo FROM Mat_ppa WHERE DATEPART(MONTH, fecha) = " & mes & " AND DATEPART(YEAR, fecha) = " & anio
    Dim rs As Object
    Set rs = cn.Execute(material_ppa)
    
    ' Obtener el resultado de la consulta
    Dim pom As Variant
    If Not rs.EOF Then
    pom = rs.GetRows()
Else
    MsgBox "Sin datos para Material PPA"
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
    Exit Sub
End If
    
    ' Cerrar la conexión y liberar los recursos
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PURGA DE INYECCIÓN") ' "Nombre de la hoja"
    
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Tableppa") ' "Nombre de la tabla"
    tbl.DataBodyRange.ClearContents ' Limpiar los datos existentes en la tabla
    tbl.DataBodyRange.Value = Application.Transpose(pom):

End Sub
```

Esta seria la forma en la que la tabla está antes de llamar a la función `MatPpa()`:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al llamar la función `MatPpa()` solo ha insertado la primer fila del resultado
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Incremento el numero de filas de la tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ejecuto de nuevo la función `MatPpa()` y ahora el numero de datos insertados es igual al numero de filas de la tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero el objetivo es que inserte en la tabla todos los resultados de la consulta independiente del numero de filas de la tabla.

Comment: `tbl.DataBodyRange.Value = Application.Transpose(pom):` meterá solo los registros que quepan en el `DataBodyRange` actual. En tu primera imagen es solo 1 fila, por eso solo mete 1. En tu siguiente imagen es 6 y por eso mete 6. Si quieres llevarte el recordset completo, usa mejor [Método Range.CopyFromRecordset (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/api/excel.range.copyfromrecordset)